# 'Dislike_count' error when using youtube_dl on Replit.com

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl, keyerror

I'm making a discord Music Bot in python and everything works fine when I run the bot on my pc, but when I run it via Replit.com it returns an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'dislike_count'
```

I know this error occurs because of a line in a DiscordUtils file `dislikes = data['dislike_count']`, so on my pc I can just comment that line out and everything works fine.

But on Replit.com there seems to be no way to change or modify installed library files, so how should I fix this issue? I also tried Heroku, but that is the same issue.

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Youtube has removed the dislike count from their API, you shouldn't get a value in that field.

Comment: What do you mean by 'you shouldn't get a value in that field.'? I'm using youtube_dl version 2021.12.17 and discord.py version 1.7.3 btw

Comment: Youtube has removed the dislike count from their API, meaning it makes sense you're not getting a value there. It seems pafy (a dependency of youtube_dl) hasn't updated to fix this yet. There's a temporary solution on [their github issues](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/pull/305#issuecomment-986212672)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay so I found my fix on [this](https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/pull/305#issuecomment-986212672) website, thanks **@Adid.**

The issue was with `pafy` and to fix this just run `pip uninstall -y pafy` in the terminal, followed by `pip install git+https://github.com/Cupcakus/pafy` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Find where you have pip installed your DiscordUtils, in the DiscordUtils folder you will find music.py. Open the file in a code editor and delete all of the strings in line 51, 67 and 87. This will fix the problem if you still have it.

Comment: Could you add a more detailed explanation for this? Why do you need this?

Comment: YouTube removed the Dislike counter, and the DiscordUtils code looks for the count in the video, but doesn't find it and it generates the error.